# GZip my AFNetworking posts to my server

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

My application posts large amounts of data, Orders with Order Items - sometimes 1000's, and I want to send it GZipped because my users also have crappy connections most of the time.

How can I accomplish this with AFnetworking?

I am currently using AFHTTPSessionManager to perform my posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AFgzipRequestSerializer`.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFgzipRequestSerializer serializerWithSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];

[manager POST:@"http://example.com/"
   parameters:@{@"foo": @"bar"}
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
}
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
}];
```

See details [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFgzipRequestSerializer).

Comment: I saw it, looks like it has not been updated for 3 years so I was wondering if it was worth using - I'll check it out

Comment: It's from the same author and it's just a serialisation with an additional gzip parameter in header. I don't think there will be any issues.